# MySQL nested table selects - don't display if outer table doesn't match inner table

Tags: mysql, select

I'm pulling a main list of directories and looping through, then nested inside the loop I'm pulling a set of notes matching each directory.

In the example below, how would I NOT show dir 3 and dir 4 listing?  These represent logos of categories and if the results are empty, I don't want those logos showing up.  I read up on INNER JOIN but it didn't seem to match this need or at least I don't understand it.

To simplify the post I eliminated a lot of html tables and the structure.  The idea is that the outer loop runs all the directories but I can't really check against the inner (that I know of) to see if it should be listed.  I'll read into the LEFT JOIN options posted below by very helpful posters.

```
$sql_dir="SELECT dirid FROM lit_directories";
$result_dir=mysql_query($sql_dir);
   while ($row_dir=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_dir)) {
edit here-->  echo $row_dir['dirid'];

   $sql_notes="SELECT notes, dirid FROM lit_notes WHERE dirid='".$row_dir['dirid']."'";
   $result_notes=mysql_query($sql_notes);
      while ($row_notes=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_notes)) {
         echo $row_notes['notes'];
      }
   }

  dirid   notes
-----------------------
| dir 1 | notes 1
|       | notes 2
|       | notes 3
-----------------------
| dir 2 | notes 1
|       | notes 2
-----------------------
| dir 3 |               <---- I don't want these last 2 dir lists to show
|       |                     since they are empty
-----------------------
| dir 4 |               <---- 
|       |                     
-----------------------
```

Comment: Is notes 3 & 4 NULL or empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql_dir="SELECT l.dirid, notes FROM lit_directories l LEFT JOIN lit_notes n  ON n.dirid = l.dirid WHERE n.notes IS NOT NULL";
$result_dir=mysql_query($sql_dir);
while ($row_dir=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_dir)) {
      echo $row_notes['notes'];
}
```

Comment: I think what might confuse me is after reading up on LEFT JOIN it appears that the results will show even if there is an empty result on some of the table columns.  I actually don't want to show those empty results.  I apologize if I'm not explaining well.  Your post might have led me to the answer though.  I'll try it out.  On this link http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php  it shows a simplified mysql query just before the LEFT JOIN example.

Comment: added the  WHERE n.notes IS NOT NULL to correct the query. This will eliminate the rows with NULL notes

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend what [Preet Sangha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30225/preet-sangha) suggested. Other way, you can skip the row if notes are not found.

for example,

```
$sql_dir="SELECT dirid FROM lit_directories";
$result_dir=mysql_query($sql_dir);
   while ($row_dir=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_dir)) {

   $sql_notes="SELECT notes, dirid FROM lit_notes WHERE dirid='".$row_dir['dirid']."'";
   $result_notes=mysql_query($sql_notes);
      while ($row_notes=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_notes)) {
         if($row_notes['notes'] == ''){
             continue;
         }
         echo $row_notes['notes'];
      }
   }
```

But better approach in term of performance, I think, Preet Sangha's solution should be used.

Comment: I'm going to make an edit to my post which I apologize for.  It's the main reason i'm confused.  The "dirid" being printed is outside the inner loop so I don't know how to check for a match or that it's blank like you did.  I'll edit my post.